# Views Block Question

Tags: views, theming, 8, blocks

I created a view that is a block.  I then wanted to create another block for that view but with different criteria.  When creating the second block, it was identical to the first block created and when I lets say change the fields, the first original block gets changed as well.  So it seems anything I do to the new block changes the first block as well.

What is the purpose of being able to create a second block but it is the exact same as the first?  I think the only difference it can have is a display name?  Can anyone explain this to me or give me an example of the purpose of this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the "For" setting in the header whenever changing almost anything.

If you want the setting to change on **both displays** choose "All displays":

[image]

If you want the setting to change on **only one display** choose "This block (override)"
[image]

Comment: I was not paying attention.  So easy.  Can I ask you if it would be ideal to have 1 view with blocks of different content.  Example I have 3 block views and they are all the same only difference is the content type being displayed.  Can I use 1 view and create 3 blocks of different content for that view? @chrishappy

Comment: @klo009 yes, just click on the +add button and select block, then just change the filter of content type and use the above answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can create another view block within same view with a difference to change the fields on both views can be done. The process is when you create a fields on second view just use override this display for each field on second view and if you want to delete some fields from second view that is being carried over from first view is by opening the popup by clicking the field in second view and select override this display option with in popupp and then remove. If you escape the step of overriding the field in second view and remove the field from second view the field will also be removed from first also.